# Is there a way to protect routes in React in server-side for non-authenticated users ? (I use firebase for authentication)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I'm creating a web app using React for client-side and Firebase and Cloud Functions for server-side. Is there a way to protect routes in server-side. All tutorials I find are about protecting routes in React.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [JWT tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) for Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually at the moment I can retrieve and verify token from client in the backend, but still didn't figure out how to protect routes in React.